# Which one is the most idiomatic way to allocate uninitialized memory in C++

Tags: c++, memory, malloc, new-operator

Option A:

`T * address = static_cast<T *>(::operator new(capacity * sizeof(T), std::nothrow));`

Option B:

`T * address = static_cast<T *>(std::malloc(capacity * sizeof(T)));`

Context:

```
template <typename T>
T * allocate(size_t const capacity) {
    if (!capacity) {
        throw some_exception;
    }
    //T * address = static_cast<T *>(std::malloc(capacity * sizeof(T)));
    //T * address = static_cast<T *>(::operator new(capacity * sizeof(T), std::nothrow));
    if (!address) {
        throw some_exception;
    }
    return address;
}
```

`std::malloc` is shorter, but `::operator new` is clearly C++ and it's probably implemented in terms of `std::malloc`. Which one is better / more idiomatic to use in C++.

Comment: Have a look at [std::aligned_storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: std::aligned_storage doesn't allocate memory

Comment: @geza  That's true. The point of my comment was to suggest allocating instances of `std::aligned_storage` instead of raw memory. The example shows that we know the memory should be large enough to hold some number of objects of type `T`. It's the portable solution.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - [malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) is defined to already allocate memory "*suitably aligned for any built-in type*". Similarly, `operator new` is [defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary#expr.new-11) as: "*The pointer returned shall be suitably aligned so that it can be converted to a pointer of any complete object type*".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I see. Now it is more clear what you wanted to say :)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: isn't `std::aligned_storage` mainly for non allocated things? Does `operator new` use information about the type it's allocating? For example, does it use alignment information when allocating the storage?

Comment: @geza no operator new doesn't know what type it is allocating and so it can't return different alignments for different objects except based on what it knows from the size of the object (eg if all 8 byte objects need at most 8 byte alignment then it is free to  align to 8 in that case, even if larger object might need 16 byte alignment). In practice this means that new and malloc actually just always align to some "big enough" alignment which works for all types with standard alignment.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: yep, that's what I know about this too. So here, `std::aligned_storage` doesn't give us anything more than `new char[size];`, does it?

Comment: @geza - I don't actually see how `std::aligned_storage` could be used to implement the `allocate()` function above at all, since you pass `Len` as a (compile-time) template argument, but `allocate` is taking a (runtime) function argument. In general, it seems like `std::aligned_storage` might give more guarantees than operator `new`: the former seems to guarantee that the storage is suitably aligned for _any_ type with size up to `Len` (with the default `Align` value) while operator new only guarantees alignment for objects with  "fundamental alignment."

Comment: In practice though, I don't see how `std::aligned_storage` with default `Align` can satisfy it's "any object" guarantee in the presence of over-aligned types (which might live in other compilation units) since they could in principle have arbitrarily large alignments.

Comment: @geza - I asked specifically about the `std::aligned_storage` behavior [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457386/how-can-stdaligned-storage-expose-correctly-aligned-storage-for-any-object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If at all possible, you should prefer to allocate memory in a type-safe way. If that's out of the question, prefer Option A, `operator new(size_t, std::nothrow)`  because:

- Operators `new` and `delete` can be overridden legally (this can be useful in custom allocator / leak detection scenarios).
- Can have an alternative allocator to deal with low memory (`set_new_handler`).
- Is much more C++.

The only reason to prefer `malloc` / `free` is if you want to optimize *reallocations* with `realloc`, which isn't supported by `operator` `new` / `delete` (realloc is [not](http://blog.httrack.com/blog/2014/04/05/a-story-of-realloc-and-laziness/) a simple free+malloc).