# How can std::aligned_storage expose correctly aligned storage for any object?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, alignment

The `std::aligned_storage` structure provides a `type` typedef that at least according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage):

> Provides the member typedef type, which is a PODType suitable for use
>   as uninitialized storage for any object whose size is at most Len and
>   whose alignment requirement is a divisor of Align.
>
> The default value of Align is the most stringent (the largest)
>   alignment requirement for any object whose size is at most Len.

In particular, with the default value of `Align`, the suitably aligned for *any object* whose size is at most Len.

Note that there are no caveats or exceptions for over-aligned types (and in any case the platform I'm using, gcc, supports at least some over-aligned types).

How can such an implementation actually work? To satisfy the requirement of "any object" it would seem that it would either:

1. On a platform where `alignof(T) <= sizeof(T)` for types `T`, need to always align to roughly `Len` bytes, since an object of size `Len` could have an alignment of up to `Len`. Of course, this would waste a lot of memory for large `Len`!
2. On a platform where `alignof(T)` may be larger than than `sizeof(T)`, I don't see how it could be implemented at all. However, it isn't [clear to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457449/is-it-always-the-case-that-sizeoft-alignoft-for-all-types-t) that such a type can even exist.

Based on [my testing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d27a419d81c12f2d), for default `Align` values, `gcc` simply always aligns to 16, regardless of len. This means the storage is *not* suitable for *any* object, but only objects of fundamental alignment (`alignof(max_align_t) == 16` on this platform).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [[meta.trans.other]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/meta.trans.other#2),

> It is implementation-defined whether any extended alignment is supported.

It's pretty annoying when they specify stuff like this after the big table without a pointer. I've just added the sentence to cppreference.

Comment: So the footnote "2" doesn't occur anywhere in the text right? What is weird though is that GCC does generally support extended alignments up to at least 128, but not here. I guess there is no constraints that extended alignment support  has be be _consistent_ in any implementation, however.