# Is it guaranteed that sizeof(T[N]) == N * sizeof(T)?

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, sizeof

I had always assumed that the size of an array of N elements of type `T`, as returned by `sizeof` was guaranteed to be exactly N times `sizeof(T)`.

The [comments on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457449/is-it-always-the-case-that-sizeoft-alignoft-for-all-types-t/46458123?noredirect=1#comment79871390_46457449) made me doubt it though. There are claims from reputable users that arrays may contain padding, which would break the equality. Of course such platforms may not exist, but are they allowed?

If allowed, this would break many common idioms, such as calculating the needed storage for an array with `N * sizeof(T)`, or calculating the number of elements in an array using `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`.

Comment: Given that `sizeof` is always dealing with the static type and not runtime values, I don't think how the actual memory behaves matters. Whether `sizeof(T[N]) == N * sizeof(T)` is a type system and preprocessor concern.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin - correct, I don't think I implied otherwise? Or perhaps it was a reply to a now-deleted comment.

Comment: I was commenting on the discussion from the thread you linked to. It may very well be the case that there are runtimes where arrays occupy more space than the sum of their element sizes, but this has no bearing on the fact that `sizeof(T[N])` is `N * sizeof(T)`.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin agreed.

Comment: Thanks for your question, I have chances to read the sizeof document, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof, you can find that in notes section, they mentioned that sizeof when apply to class type, its result will include additional padding required to insert that object to array.

Comment: I originally looked at this topic because of another question. I'm not sure if it directly asked the same thing and this is a duplicate, or if it was tangential like to your other question; I'll post a link if I find it.

Comment: Arrays cannot contain any padding other than paddind at the end of each individual element, which is already included in sizeof(element).

Answer (score 11):

Yes. *[expr.sizeof]* includes this bit about `sizeof`:

> When applied to an array, the result is the total number of bytes in the array. This implies that the size of an array of *n* elements is *n* times the size of an element.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know where "the total number of bytes in the array" is defined, and I think that the statement "This implies..." is false; I think the rest of the standard without that statement does not imply there is no invisible padding at the end. If I'm correct about that, then the question is whether that sentence counts as equivalent to "It is guaranteed that the size of an array of *n* elements is *n* times the size of an element" or just a problem in the standard.

Comment: @DanielH Of course it is true, there is no padding in the end of the array. It is not mentioned anywhere in the standard that such padding may exist. "An object of array type contains a contiguously allocated non-empty
set of N subobjects of type T." Nothing more. Only class types may have padding bytes.

Comment: @n.m. If you go by “of course”, then you’re going to get undefined behavior fairly quickly. Now that you point out that quote, I do remember seeing it, but people weren’t sure on whether it meant it had to contain *only* those things or not.

Comment: @DanielH standard mentions more than once that the size of the array is the size of its element times the size of the element. This answer quotes one such mention, there are others. Whether they are legally normative or not, I don't really care. This is clearly the intent which is no less important than the actual wording.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of `sizeof` is it includes the relevant padding. Every element of an array is exactly `sizeof(T)` bytes after the previous element. So the size of the entire array is `N * sizeof(T)`.

Comment: I think the question is if `sizeof(T)` allows extra padding *just for the array*. All of the individual objects have padding, but does the standard allow the array itself to have padding beyond beyond the padding of the elements?

Comment: Where would that extra padding come from?

Comment: From the compiler saying that `sizeof(T[N]) > N * sizeof(T)`, so it puts extra padding at the end. The C++ standard doesn’t say very much about layout, and as long as the extra padding maintained the alignment requirements of `T[N]`, which would need to be at least those of `T` (I think that is required to be exactly the same, but I’m not sure), it would be allowed.

Comment: @DanielH When discussing `sizeof`, the standard says that padding may be added at the end of class types and this padding is included in the size, for the purpose of placing objects of these types in an array. In the very next sentence it discusses `sizeof` applied to array types, and it doesn't say that padding may be added at the end of those (that's what @melpomene quotes). Why invent things that the standard never mentions?