# Allocate aligned memory on the stack like _alloca

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17, c11, alloca

The documentation for `_alloca()` says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca):

> The _alloca routine returns a void pointer to the allocated space,
>   which is guaranteed to be suitably aligned for storage of any type of
>   object.

However, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/alloca) it says:

> _alloca is required to be 16-byte aligned and additionally required to use a frame pointer.

So it seems that in the first reference they forgot about 32-byte aligned AVX/AVX2 types like `__m256d`.

Another thing that confuses me is that the first page says `_alloca()` is deprecated, while it suggests to use instead a function that may allocate memory from the heap rather than the stack (which is unacceptable in my multi-threaded application).

So can someone point me whether there is some modern (perhaps, new C/C++ standard?) way for aligned stack memory allocation?

**Clarification 1**: Please, don't provide solutions which require the array size to be compile-time constant. My function allocates variable number of array items depending on run-time parameter value.

Comment: First, decide if you are asking about C or C++, though  `_alloca` is not part of either of them.

Comment: `alloca` align allocation on 16byte. if you need another align - allocate more memory and align yourself

Comment: Will `std::aligned_storage` work for your needs? You can specify the alignment as the second template parameter and it comes from the stack given the example implementation which uses `alignas`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage

Comment: What is `alignof(__m256d)`, for the benefit of people who don't have your platform extensions?

Comment: @KerrekSB, it was in the question: 32 bytes.

Comment: @SergeRogatch: Yes, sure, but is that literally the value of the alignof expression, or something you got from somewhere else?

Comment: if you need allocate 32byte allign memory of size `cb` - `PBYTE pb = (PBYTE)alloca(31 + cb);
 pb = (PBYTE)((ULONG_PTR)(pb + 31) & ~31);`

Comment: @SergeRogatch Are you sure the first reference is incorrect? They are perfectly consistent. Something guaranteed to fit any type can also be only guaranteed to align on a 16-byte boundary because there might exist machines that don't have any 32-byte aligned types. Obviously, on machines that do have types with 32-byte alignment requirement, it would be 32-byte aligned.

Comment: @KerrekSB , I've double-checked with `std::cout << alignof(__m256d) << std::endl;`, it's 32.

Comment: @Joe, no, `std::aligned_storage` doesn't seem eligible because it requires the array length to be compile-time constant.

Comment: OK -- that's *extended alignment* then, and support for that is implementation-defined. `max_align_t` only gives you the largest non-extended alignment, so the phrase "for any type" is not quite accurate. You can use the `std::align` helper function to align memory manually.

Answer (score 5):

Overallocate with _alloca(), then hand-align. Like this:

```
const int align = 32;
void *p =_alloca(n + align - 1);
__m256d *pm = (__m256d *)((((int_ptr_t)p + align - 1) / align) * align);
```

Replace `const` with `#define`, if necessary.

Comment: better `(__m256d *)(((UINT_PTR)p + (align - 1)) & ~(align - 1))`

Comment: Either works :) The point is, overallocate to the worst possible case - (alignment-1) extra bytes. Then round up.

Comment: You actually only need to over allocate by 16 bytes, then check `p % 32 != 0`. If it's not 0 add 16 and done. The address needs to be 16 bytes aligned by spec.

Comment: Is that really what the spec says? I thought it was a GCC implementation quirk. Cite maybe?

Answer (score 2):

`_alloca()` is certainly not a standard or portable way of handling alignment on the stack.  Luckily in C++11 we got `alignas` and `std::aligned_storage`.  Neither of these forces you to put anything on the heap, so they should work for your use case.  For example, to align an array of structs to a 32 byte boundary:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct bar { int member; /*...*/ };
void fun() {
  std::aligned_storage<sizeof(bar), 32>::type array[16];
  auto bar_array = reinterpret_cast<bar*>(array);
}
```

Or if you just want to align a single variable on the stack to a boundary:

```
void bun() {
  alignas(32) bar b;
}
```

You can also use the `alignof` operator to get the alignment requirements for a given type.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 introduced the `alignof` operator:

> An alignof expression yields the alignment requirement of its operand type.

You can use it as follows:

```
struct s {};
typedef s __attribute__ ((aligned (64))) aligned_s;

std::cout << alignof(aligned_s); // Outputs: 64
```

**Note:** If your type's alignment is bigger than its size, the compiler won't let you declare arrays of the array type(See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457449/is-it-always-the-case-that-sizeoft-alignoft-for-all-object-types-t/46458123#46458123)):

> error: alignment of array elements is greater than element size

**But**, if your type's alignment is smaller then its size, you can 
safely allocate arrays:

```
aligned_s arr[32];
-- OR --
constexpr size_t arr_size = 32;
aligned_s arr[arr_size];
```

Compilers that support VLAs, will allow those for the newly defined type as well.

Comment: Does this approach allow non-constant array size? Array size changes at runtime between calls of the function where I need `_alloca()`.

Comment: *cl* not support non-constant array size

Comment: @SergeRogatch, Dynamic Arrays (a.k.a VLAs) were [considered as part of the standard](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/04/trip-report-iso-c-spring-2013-meeting) but didn't make it. Though, G++ (4.6.3) and Clang (900.0.38) allow it.

Answer (score 1):

The "modern" way is:

[**Don't make variable-length allocation on the stack.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018853/why-is-the-use-of-alloca-not-considered-good-practice)

In the context of your question - wanting to allocate on the heap but refraining from doing so - I'm assuming you may be allocating more than some small compile-time constant amount of memory. In that case, you're simply going to smash your stack with that `alloca()` call. Instead, use a thread-safe memory allocator. I'm sure there are libraries for this on GitHub (and at worst you could protect allocation calls with a global mutex, although that's slow if you need lots of them).

On the other hand, if you do know in advance what's the cap on the allocation size - just pre-allocate that much memory in thread-local storage; or use a fixed-size local array (which will get allocated on the stack).

Comment: *Don't make variable-length allocation on the stack* - this is why ?

Comment: really variable-length allocation is very effective on relative small blocks. if we do this in user mode and in own exe file (so we exactly know the stack size and can set it at build time). usually we free allocate hundreds of thousands bytes in stack. another question, when we do this first time and allocate several pages(4KB) or more this will be slowly compare heap allocation (if special not move guard page down before). and in case stack overflow behavior is defined. (*all this for windows*)