# Loading and storing long doubles in x86-64

Tags: x86, x86-64, compiler-optimization, x87

I noticed a weird thing today. When copying a `long double`<sup>1</sup> all of `gcc`, `clang` and `icc` generate `fld` and `fstp` instructions, with `TBYTE` memory operands.

That is, the following function:

```
void copy_prim(long double *dst, long double *src) {
    *src = *dst;
}
```

[Generates](https://godbolt.org/g/yjyjWg) the following assembly:

```
copy_prim(long double*, long double*):
  fld TBYTE PTR [rdi]
  fstp TBYTE PTR [rsi]
  ret
```

Now according to [Agner's tables](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#manual_instr_tab) this is a poor choice for performance, as `fld` takes four uops (none fused) and `fstp` takes a whopping **seven** uops (none fused) versus say a single fused uop each for `movaps` to/from an `xmm` register.

Interestingly, `clang` starts using `movaps` as soon as you put the `long double` in a `struct`. The following code:

```
struct long_double {
    long double x;
};

void copy_ld(long_double *dst, long_double *src) {
    *src = *dst;
}
```

[Compiles](https://godbolt.org/g/yjyjWg) to the same assembly with `fld`/`fstp` as previously shown for `gcc` and `icc` but `clang` now uses:

```
copy_ld(long_double*, long_double*):
  movaps xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdi]
  movaps xmmword ptr [rsi], xmm0
  ret
```

Oddly, if you stuff an additional `int` member into the `struct` (which *doubles* its size to 32 bytes due to alignment), all compilers generate SSE-only copy code:

```
copy_ldi(long_double_int*, long_double_int*):
  movdqa xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdi]
  movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsi], xmm0
  movdqa xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdi+16]
  movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsi+16], xmm0
  ret
```

Is there any functional reason to copy floating point values with `fld` and `fstp` or is just a missed optimization?

---

<sup>1</sup> Although a `long double` (i.e., x86 extended precision float) is nominally 10 bytes on x86, it has `sizeof == 16` and `alignof == 16` since alignments have to be a power of two and the size [must usually be at least as large as the alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46457449/149138).

Comment: A 10-byte store (8 + 2 I assume) and a 16-byte reload hits a store-forwarding stall.  Other than that, seems like pure missed optimization to use the default code-gen for cases where you aren't going to operate on it.

Comment: This reminds me of the missed-optimizations for `atomic<double>` load/store: often bouncing to integer registers even when it doesn't need to CAS, just `mov`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055402/atomic-double-floating-point-or-sse-avx-vector-load-store-on-x86-64

Comment: It's weird how tunneling through a `struct` sometimes avoids it. It seems like what happens is that "scalarization" is kicking in for `gcc` so that the simple struct with one `long double` just ends up looking like a `long double` and then goes back to the bad codegen (but not on clang). When you add enough other stuff, that stops and it goes to the usual struct copy logic which is much better. Oddly `icc` still handles _some_ more complex weirdly, like [this one](https://godbolt.org/g/1FtsyW). Try removing or adding an `int` member and the code totally changes.

Comment: I think you're just seeing that compilers know how to copy whole structs around, regardless of contents.  You're just getting the default code-gen for loading "a struct", or "a long double" when the compiler sees through the struct and "optimizes" it to what it would do for a single primitive type.  It's only with `long double` that this is particularly bad.  (Although really copying around `double` with SSE2 instead of x87 is also better, even with `-mfpmath=387`.  There's no actual ALU uop, but the store-reload latency is higher by 1c for `fld`/`fstp` than `movq`/`movq` (SKL from Agner Fog)

Comment: @peter did you check out the weird ICC behavior for `long double` plus 4 `int`s.

Comment: No, I hadn't looked at that.  Looks like when there's no padding, ICC "sees through" the struct and shoots itself in the foot.  ICC is very good at auto-vectorizing (including search loops with data-dependent trip counts), but worse than gcc/clang at a lot of other stuff.  (And BTW, ICC18 properly supports `-march=skylake` and so on now.  ICC17 only seemed to recognize `-march=native` on Godbolt, or maybe some weird stuff like `corei7-avx` but not `skylake-avx512`.  But that only affects code-gen if there's any padding: https://godbolt.org/g/SttDQT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a big missed-optimization for code that needs to copy `long double` without processing it.  `fstp m80`/`fld m80` round-trip latency 8 cycles on Skylake, vs. 5 for `movdqa` store-forwarding from store to reload.  More importantly, Agner lists `fstp m80` as one per 5 clocks throughput, so there's something non-pipelined going on!

The only possible benefit I can think of is store-forwarding from a still-in-flight `long double` store.  Consider a data-dependency chain that involves some x87 math, a `long double` store, then your function, then a `long double` load and more x87 math.  According to Agner's tables, `fld`/`fstp` will add 8 cycles, but `movdqa` will see a store-forwarding stall and add 5 + 11 cycles or so for a slow-path store-fowarding.

Probably the lowest latency strategy to copy an `m80` would be 64-bit + 16-bit integer `mov`/`movzx` load/store instructions.  We know that `fstp m80` and `fld m80` use 2 separate store-data (port 4) or load (p23) uops, and I think we can assume it's broken up as 64-bit mantissa and 16-bit sign:exponent.

Of course for throughput, and latency in cases other than store-forwarding, `movdqa` seems like by far the best choice because as you point out, the ABI guarantees 16-byte alignment.  A 16-byte store can forward to a `fld m80`.

---

**The same argument applies for copying `double` or `float` with integer vs. x87 (e.g. 32-bit code)**: `fld m32`/`fstp m32` has 1 cycle higher round-trip latency than SSE `movd`, and 2 cycles higher latency than integer `mov` on Sandybridge-family CPUs.  (Unlike PowerPC / Cell load-hit-store, there's no penalty for store-forwarding from FP stores to integer loads.  x86's strong memory ordering model wouldn't allow separate store buffers for FP vs. integer, if that's what PPC does.)

Once the compiler realizes that it's not going to use any FP instructions on a `float` / `double` / `long double`, it should usually replace the load/store with non-x87.  But copying a `double` or `float` with x87 is fine if integer / SSE register pressure is a problem.

Integer register pressure in 32-bit code is almost always high, and `-mfpmath=sse` is the default for 64-bit code.  You could imagine rare cases where using x87 to copy a `double` in 64-bit code would be worth it, but compilers would be more likely to make things worse than better if they went looking for places to use x87.  gcc has `-mfpmath=sse+387`, but it's not usually very good.  (And that's not even considering physical register file pressure from using x87 + SSE.  Hopefully an "empty" x87 state doesn't use any physical registers.  `xsave` knows about parts of the architectural state being empty so it can avoid saving them...)