# Is it possible to have a type with a larger alignment than its own size?

Tags: rust, alignment, memory-layout

Is it ever possible to have a type in Rust with a larger alignment than its own size? Conversely, does the rust compiler always add padding to a type to make its size at least a multiple of its alignment?

This simple example code would seem to indicate that the answer is no, all types have a size that is a multiple of their alignment, but I wanted to make sure there aren't more esoteric possibilities.

```rust
use std::mem::{size_of, align_of};

struct b1 {
    byte: u8
}

#[repr(align(4))]
struct b4 {
    byte: u8
}

struct b5 {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
    c: u8,
    d: u8,
    e: u8,
}

#[repr(align(8))]
struct b8 {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
    c: u8,
    d: u8,
    e: u8,
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(size_of::<b1>(), 1);
    assert_eq!(align_of::<b1>(), 1);

    assert_eq!(size_of::<b4>(), 4);
    assert_eq!(align_of::<b4>(), 4);

    assert_eq!(size_of::<b5>(), 5);
    assert_eq!(align_of::<b5>(), 1);

    assert_eq!(size_of::<b8>(), 8);
    assert_eq!(align_of::<b8>(), 8);
}
```

There is a similar question for [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457449/is-it-always-the-case-that-sizeoft-alignoft-for-all-object-types-t), where the answer seems to be "not in standard C++, but some compiler extensions support it. You can't create an array of T in that case".

Comment: Note that "a is a multiple of b" doesn't quite imply that "a is at least b". Indeed, `()` [has size 0 and alignment 1.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=db27fe5e6545bd537bdd2d4a537de20a)

Comment: True, but in this specific use case that's actually okay. I'm basically trying to determine it's possible for T to have no padding but [T; 4] TO have padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rust reference has this to say about size and alignment (emphasis mine):

> ### [Size and Alignment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#size-and-alignment)
>
> [...]
>
> The size of a value is the offset in bytes between successive elements in an array with that item type including alignment padding. **The size of a value is always a multiple of its alignment.** The size of a value can be checked with the `size_of_val` function.