# C++: Is there ever a reason to make alignof > sizeof for a type

Tags: c++, types, alignment, simd, sizeof

As indicated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457449/is-it-always-the-case-that-sizeoft-alignoft-for-all-object-types-t), it is possible to have alignment greater than size for a type, you just can't make an array of it.
However you can make an array of char[alignof(T)] and reinterpret_cast to insert elements there.

So the question becomes, are there any situations where it would *be useful* to have alignof(T) > sizeof(T)?
Only one I can think of would be to align to SIMD boundaries.

Comment: "Possible" is a bit misleading if it requires compiler extensions.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size has some examples, where you might have a small object but want to ensure that it lives within a single cache line (promoting true sharing / "constructive interference"); or to ensure that you never have two of them in the same cache line (avoiding false sharing / "destructive interference").

Answer (score 5):

It's useful to align the *start of an array* of `T` more than `alignof(T)`, but that's alignment of the array object, not of the element type.  Like `alignas(32) float arr[1024];`, allowing aligned SIMD loads/stores with 16 or 32-byte vectors so they can't split across cache lines.

Last I checked with GCC, if you typedef a version of `float` with `__attribute__((aligned(16)))`, each element takes 16 bytes if you make an array, so the element size effectively grows, including padding.  And the linked Q&A shows that clang won't let you make an array.

Comment: It's interesting that GCC is even able to propagate the over-alignment from a struct to its members. Might be useful for things like memory-mapped file formats. https://godbolt.org/z/WsET3dTrz